# Django - how to automatically create a new model instance when another model instance is created

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have an `Order` and `Notification` Model, whenever there is a new order model instance, i want to immediately create a notification for the new order, i wrote some functions in the models but when there is a new order, the notification instance does not get created. i still think there should be a better way to do this, how can i go about this?

models.py

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="service_orders")
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="seller")

    def create_notification(self):
        create_notification = Notification.objects.create(provider=self.seller, service=self.service, order=self , notification_type='new_order')
        create_notification.save()
        return create_notification



class Notification(models.Model):
    provider = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="provider_notifications")
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="service_notifications")
    order = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="service_order")
    notification_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=NOTIFICATION_TYPE, default="none")
```

Comment: Where are u calling the `create_notification` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like the following:

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="service_orders")
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="seller")

    def create_notification(self):
        create_notification = Notification.objects.create(
            provider=self.seller, service=self.service, order=self , notification_type='new_order')
        create_notification.save()
        return create_notification

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        super().save(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using, update_fields=update_fields)
        self.create_notification()
```

Where `save` method will be overwriten and once you persist it in the database layer then you can safety call the method `create_notification`.

Best way to achieve it could be using signals to decouple the logic from the model and manage it in a separate business logic component, but if you don't mind applying the best practices you are good to go with the solution.